# Let $D$ be one domain and $M$ and $N$ are different maximal ideals. Show that $M + N = D$.

Tags: ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Since $ M $ is maximal then $ M \subsetneq D $ the same is for $ N $, so there is no $ J $, such that $M \subsetneq J \subset D$ and $N \subsetneq J \subset D$. Given this, can I conclude that $M + N = D$?.

Comment: Yes as $M+N$ is a an ideal properly containing $M$.

Comment: This has nothing to do with domains.